# Eject SD card via ADB

Tags: adb, external-sd, sd-card, storage, command-line

Is it possible to emulate physical eject/cut power supply for SD card in Android via ADB terminal?

What I'm looking for is something similar to the functionality achieved on GNU/Linux for USB devices via /sys/bus/* files.
However, if there is other "Pure Android" way, it will also suffice as long as it works.

The important point is that SD card should not be properly unmounted, but rather appear to the system as a sudden eject.

Comment: Any specific reason why?

Comment: @GokulNC for stability testing in case of sudden storage removal.